# How do I solve "index unique_schema_migrations already exists" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

Running `rake db:migrate` followed by `rake test:units` yields the following:

```
rake test:functionals
(in /projects/my_project)
rake aborted!
SQLite3::SQLException: index unique_schema_migrations already exists: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "ts_schema_migrations" ("version")
```

The relevant part of `db/schema.rb` is as follows:

```
create_table "ts_schema_migrations", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.string "version", :null => false
end

add_index "ts_schema_migrations", ["version"], :name => "unique_schema_migrations", :unique => true
```

I'm not manually changing this index anywhere, and I'm using Rails' default SQLite3 adapter with a brand new database.  (That is, running `rm db/*sqlite3` before `rake db:migrate` doesn't help.)

Is the `test:units` task perhaps trying to re-load the schema?  If so, why?  Shouldn't it recognize the schema is already up to date?

Comment: There are definitely no other index declarations for the schema_migrations table in the schema.rb.  The bug doesn't happen on MySQL, interestingly enough, though.

Comment: It may also have something to do with my using table_name_prefix.  When doing a rake db:schema:load, I get doubly-prefixed tables.

Answer (score 15):

In SQLite, index name uniqueness is enforced at the database level.  In MySQL, uniqueness is enforced only at the table level.  That's why your migrations work in the latter and not the former: you have two indexes with the same name on different tables.

Rename the index, or find and rename the other `unique_schema_migrations` index, and your migrations should work.

Comment: I had the same problem in Laravel, when testing starting to migrate it says index already exists. I changed all the indices to have unique name (prepending the table name) and it worked. This is the correct answer I believe.

Answer (score 2):

In your database.yml file are your environments setup up to connect to different databases for Development and Test?

IE:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/dev.sqlite3
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to search if your schema.rb file does not contain other declarations that create an index with the same name: `unique_schema_migrations`